# Selection of Irregular part of an Image ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an image shown below:

[image]

In which i have to select all parts one by one and change their colour, I have tried many methods but couldn't able to solve this. I have tried Bezier Path but no success.

This is the code am using currently for selection of any part based on colour, and then i have changed that colour to red as shown below:

[image]

But the problem is I have to change colour of only that part of image which i have selected not all which have same colour.

Any idea how to solve this.

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:_bodyImgView]; //where image was tapped

    NSLog(@"X = %f \n Y= %f",point.x,point.y);

    pickedColor = [self.view colorOfPoint:point image:_bodyImgView.image];

    NSString *col = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pickedColor];

    NSLog(@"color %@",pickedColor);

    if (![col isEqualToString:@"UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 0"]) {

    UIImage *img = [self.view replaceColor:pickedColor inImage:_bodyImgView.image 
    withTolerance:25.0];

    [_bodyImgView setImage:img];
    }
}
```

`colorOfPoint:image` is a method to extract colour from picked point.
`replaceColor:inImage:withTolerance:` is the method to replace the picked color.

Comment: hey, I suggest you use an SVG for the same. The advantage is that you can get separate Calayers for each part of the body and you can change the color as per your requirement. Check this demo https://github.com/ArthurGuibert/FSInteractiveMap , it demonstrates a map, but it pretty much suits your requirement.

Comment: This [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) looks like it will work with Jen Jose suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to be able to cope with any image, or is this a fixed image or one of a few you can preprocess? Ideally, you'd create several images, each containing one selectable region only (and the rest transparent). Then it's a matter of just looping over the images and finding one where the corresponding point is opaque, and filling the image in a blend mode that preserves transparency.

If that is not an option, maybe you could perform a seed fill to generate a mask (start searching from the click position and take any color until you hit a white pixel), then apply that mask and then perform the blend mode painting, only touching the white pixels.

Alternately, if you're manually walking the picture to seed fill already, you could look at each pixel and manually apply the color to it, maybe by determining how much blue it contains and then generating a pixel that has that amount of blue instead.